# php - how to check if a date is in a given season (regardless of the current year)?

Tags: php, date, range

**High Season:** 
April 28 - September 30, 
December 27 - January 3

**Low Season:** 
October 1 - December 26, 
January 4 - April 27

---

I gave a date to check: 2014-02-18 and I want to have TRUE or FALSE in case of which season includes it. How to do it regardless of the current year?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$day = $d->format('j');
$month = $d->format('n');

if($month == 1 && $day <= 3) {
    return 'high';
} elseif $month < 4 || ($month == 4 && $day < 28)) {
    return 'low';
} elseif($month == 4 && $day >= 28) {
    return 'high';
} elseif($month < 10) {
    return 'high';
} elseif($month < 12 || ($month == 12 && $day < 27)) {
    return 'low';
} elseif($month == 12 && $day >= 27) {
    return 'high';
}
```

Comment: Why was this downrated? It does exactly what the OP requested and does it well. The fact that there are multiple possible answers doesn't automatically make it a _bad_ answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try with simple date comparing:

```php
function is_high_season($date) {
    $md = gmdate('m-d', strtotime($date));
    return 
        ('03-28' <= $md && $md <= '09-30') || 
        ('12-27' <= $md && $md <= '12-31') || 
        ('01-01' <= $md && $md <= '01-03');
}
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/98181)</kbd>

Comment: @quardas: why would you use solution with 2x more `if` statements? Is this solution not working for you?

Answer (score -1):

```
 $Date = date('Y-m-d');
    $Date=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($Date));;
    //echo $Date; // echos today! 
    $hiDateBegin = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("28/04/2014"));
    $hiDateEnd = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("30/09/2014"));
    $hiDateBegin2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("27/12/2014"));
    $hiDateEnd2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("03/01/2015"));

    $lowDateBegin = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("01/10/2014"));
    $lowDateEnd = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("26/12/2014"));
    $lowDateBegin2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("04/01/2015"));
    $lowDateEnd2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("27/04/2015"));

    if (($Date > $hiDateBegin) && ($Date < $hiDateEnd))
    {
      echo "is Hi Season";
    }
    if (($Date > $hiDateBegin2) && ($Date < $hiDateEnd2))
    {
      echo "is Hi Season";
    }
if (($Date > $lowDateBegin) && ($Date < $lowDateEnd))
    {
      echo "is Low Season";
    }
    if (($Date > $lowDateBegin2) && ($Date < $lowDateEnd2))
    {
      echo "is Low Season";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Date doesn't fall in a season!";  
    }
```

Comment: Why was this downrated? It does exactly what the OP requested and does it well. The fact that there are multiple possible answers doesn't automatically make it a _bad_ answer.

Comment: @Tularis: some1 here likes to downvote wihtout a comment ;( I think it was downvoted because this code will not work for any other years other than 2014?